# Xcode assistant not showing the view controller when trying to connect storyboard to view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

Hi I'm trying to connect my storyboard objects to the view controller like normal but the assistant keeps showing the wrong file [image]

For the record this is my first time using a tabbed app template so I'm not sure if that's affecting anything. How can I connect the storyboard objects to the swift file if my assistant doesn't want to work?

Comment: Do not use an assistant pane for this. Just use a normal split pane.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens, on your screen shot just press command+shift+o when xcodes panel's are splited, type name of your view controller and hit enter, you will get storyboard and your view controller.